# Wireguard performance on Linux and SBCs Banana Pi/Orange PI zero 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireguard, single-board

So I have an issue with WireGuard performance.

EDIT: I tested it in an Ubuntu VM on a Ryzen 9 with the same results.

The plan is to use an SBC as a WG proxy. On both SBCs I get ~40 mbits with my current provider, Mullvad. Without WG I get the max speeds, 100mbits for Banana Pi M1 and 200mbits for the Orange Pi Zero 3.

I monitored the CPU usage and it is nowhere near max. On Banana Pi running speedtest it's around 40-50% per core. On Orange Pi Zero 3 it's 5-10% on some cores.

I tried a local WG server hosted on Orange Pi, I get max speeds between the SBCs, so 100mbit as Banana PI has only 100mbit ethernet.

What gives? Using the same Mullvad endpoint, I get 200mbit from multiple PCs. At first I thought that CPU would be a limiting factor, but seeing the same performance from both SBC, and the CPU usage, it has to be something else, but I'm at a loss where to look next.

Please advise.

Comment: Tested it in an Ubuntu VM on a Ryzen 9 host, getting same speeds. Either it's a Wireguard or Mullvad issue.